# Need to build a pyramid with spaces between numbers and stars

Tags: c, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

```
    1
    **
 2       3
***      ****
```

The pyramid is supposed to look like this with a use specified number of rows. I am supposed to use for loops. I'm really confused about how to add the proper amount of spaces between the numbers and stars, though. Also, how to get the right number to display for each row, and what condition to use to stop the numbers at the right amount. Here is what I have so far:

```
{

int userinput, rows, space, stspace, stars, num;

//int startingnum;

int i;

printf("Enter the number of rows: ");

scanf("%d",&userinput);

printf("\n");

    for(rows=1; rows<=userinput; rows++)
    //printf("\n");
        {
            printf("\n");
            //for(i=1; i <= rows; i++)
            //{
            //startingnum += i;
            //}

                if(rows%2!=0)
                    {
                    for(space=1; space<=(userinput)/(rows+1); space++)
                    printf("-");
                    {
                        for(num=1; num<=rows; num++)
                        printf("%d",num);
                    }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    for(stspace=1; stspace<=(userinput)*(rows); stspace++)
                    printf("-");
                        {
                        for(stars=num+1; stars<=num+rows+1;stars++)
                            printf("*");
                        }

                    }
        }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: space is declared, the formatting of the code was weird when I pasted it in so I might have accidentally deleted the declaration when I was fixing it up. I'll edit.

Comment: hint : last_number = rows * (rows + 1) / 2. element_max_width = last_number + 1.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\n");
#if 0
Draw the following when rows is 2
[    ] represents one element. [] is for easy understanding for a element

[    ][ 1  ]
[    ][ ** ]
[ 2  ][    ][ 3  ]
[*** ][    ][****]
#endif
    int last_number = rows * (rows + 1) / 2;
    int element_width = last_number + 1;

    char blank_element[element_width +1];//+1 for NUL
    char stars_element[element_width +1];
    char work_element[element_width +1];
    char str_num[element_width +1];
    void repeatStringOutput(const char *str, int times);

    //make blank element
    memset(blank_element, ' ', element_width);
    blank_element[element_width] = 0;
    //initialize stars element
    strcpy(stars_element, "*");

    int num = 1;
    for(int r = 1; r <= rows; ++r){
        //print pre-blank-element
        repeatStringOutput(blank_element, rows - r);
        for(int c = 0; c < r; ++c){
            int len = sprintf(str_num, "%d", num + c);
            if(c)//print blank element between stars element
                fputs(blank_element, stdout);
            strcpy(work_element, blank_element);//fill spaces
            memcpy(work_element + (element_width - len)/2, str_num, len);//centering
            fputs(work_element, stdout);
        }
        puts("");
        repeatStringOutput(blank_element, rows - r);
        for(int c = 0; c < r; ++c){
            strcpy(stars_element + num++, "*");
            if(c)
                fputs(blank_element, stdout);
            strcpy(work_element, blank_element);
            memcpy(work_element + (element_width - num)/2, stars_element, num);
            fputs(work_element, stdout);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

void repeatStringOutput(const char *str, int times){
    while(times--)
        fputs(str, stdout);
}
```